# titanium multiple recipients email dialog

Tags: email, titanium

im using titanium and need to send an email to multiple recipients. the [official docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.EmailDialog) only show how to send to one individual email address.

can someone please give a more concrete example how the getToRecipients and setToRecipients methods are applied correctly so that an email is sent to multiple recipients?

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149943/emaildialog-gettorecipients-does-not-work

i need to pass an array (contacts) to the emailDialog.ToRecipients property:
 ["email@example.net","email2@example.net"]

the code below does not work with this error message (ive also tried it unsuccessfully without the "[]" in setToRecipients):

> Basic functions[2807:70b] 
>   ["email@example.net","email2@example.net"]is not a valid email
>   address.

```
var emails = JSON.stringify(contacts);
var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();
emailDialog.setToRecipients([emails]);
emailDialog.subject = "Hello from Titanium";
emailDialog.messageBody = '<b>Appcelerator Titanium Rocks!</b>';
emailDialog.open();
```

thx for any info on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
 emailDialog.setToRecipients(contacts);
```

The Appcelerator Documentation says that [EmailDialog.toRecipients](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.EmailDialog-property-toRecipients) is an String [].

See u!

Comment: looks like i can only accept one answer unfortunately. Thanks (again)!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you pass your contacts through `JSON.stringify` and then put it inside array with one element?

[`EmailDialog.setToRecipients`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.EmailDialog-method-setToRecipients) method requires array of strings, and every single one string should be proper email address. To make it work change your code into:

```
var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();
emailDialog.setToRecipients(contacts);
emailDialog.subject = "Hello from Titanium";
emailDialog.messageBody = "<b>Appcelerator Titanium Rocks!</b>";
emailDialog.open();
```

I'm assuming that `contacts` variable contains this array (based on your error message):

```
var contacts = ["email@example.net","email2@example.net"];
```